# How to check app for compatibility with previous macOS versions?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

My app works well in macOS 10.14, but breaks in macOS 10.13. How do I debug it in Xcode, having macOS 10.14 installed? Or at least how do I know what can go wrong, maybe there is some static code check?

I guess the problem could be in this code:

```
    private static func isSystemDarkModeEnabled() -> Bool {
        let global = UserDefaults.standard.persistentDomain(forName: UserDefaults.globalDomain)
        let style = global!["AppleInterfaceStyle"]
        if style != nil && (style as! String).lowercased() == "dark" {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private class SystemDarkModeChangeObserver {
        static func register() {
            SystemDarkModeChangeObserver.shared = SystemDarkModeChangeObserver()
        }

        private static var shared: SystemDarkModeChangeObserver?

        private init() {
            DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onChange), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification"), object: nil)
        }

        @objc func onChange() {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the deployment target in the general project settings. Xcode should tell you what you're using that is not available in that target.

Xcode defaults to target the version installed on your development machine.

Comment: 10.13 is listed there, but I have no warnings. I added a code sample, where could be the problem.

Comment: Dark mode is new in Mojave. Did you try setting the target to 10.13?

Comment: Yes, I have 10.13 set. Users, that use 10.13 report that it doesn't work. Maybe I could install 10.13 and Xcode in VM, but I think it requires too much time.

Comment: Then it's telling you which methods/properties are not available before Mojave. In your sample, it looks as if you're using dark mode, which is definitely not available before 10.14. Just take out those calls, you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete Derived Data,

You can go to File > Workspace Settings if you are in a workspace environment or File > Project Settings for a regular project environment. Then click over the little grey arrow under Derived data section and select your project folder to delete it.

if pod are used than deintegrate and reinstalling all pod files again.

Hope this works for you!